# Remove Last Character of URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Somehow google managed to pickup some URLs on my site with a ) at the end which is causing a bunch of 404 links. The links look something like this:

> "http://mysite.com/page.php?id=42523"

but what google has in its search results is:

> "http://mysite.com/page.php?id=42523)"

Is there a way with .htaccess that I can determine if a url ends with ) and redirect it to the proper URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)\)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1 [L,R=301]
```